# Is the subgroup $H:=\langle xyxy\rangle$ normal in $G:=\langle x,y\mid x^3=e, y^2=e\rangle$? If so, find $G/H$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G=\langle x,y\mid x^3=e, y^2=e\rangle$ and otherwise unrestricted.

Let $H=\langle xyxy\rangle$.

Is $H\triangleleft G$?

And in that case, what is
$$G/H$$
isomorphic to?

---

If it is a normal subgroup, I'd suspect $G/H\cong D_3$, but is that really true?

Comment: If a subgroup is normal, then it is invariant under conjugation, meaning $\forall a\in G$, $aHa^{-1}=H$ (note that individual elements may not map back to themselves, but elsewhere in $H$). Does that happen in this case (what do the $h\in H$ look like?)

Comment: On the other hand, if you define $H$ as the *normal* closure of $xyxy$, ie the smallest normal subgroup containing $xyxy$, then you do get $D_3$ in the quotient.

Comment: It seems it can't be. There doesn't seem any way to write $x(xyxy)x^2$ in the form $xyxy\cdots xyxy$. Thanks.

I'll think about the normal closure of  $xyxy$.

Comment: [Here's the start of a chat about my (admittedly overthought yet rather shallow) attempt at answering this.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48125846#48125846) I got fed up after about an hour and had to move on to other things.

Comment: I've checked in GAP whether the subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$. The code `IsNormal(G,H);` with the standard definitions of `G` and `H` was inconclusive.